# Google Apps - can be uninstalled and replaced by your own preferred system applications

Tags: applications, file-system, rom, system-apps, stock-rom

Can we all change the basic system apps installed on our phones? (e.g. contacts, phone, messaging etc.) And replacing it with new applications that can't harm and destroy the phone's stock rom?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can... For example [QKSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moez.QKSMS&hl=en)
for SMS/ MMS, [Zero Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.zerodialer&hl=en)
for dialer and contact and so on.
These apps can be used without uninstalling the existing default apps.
If you want to completely remove default app then you have to root your phone and use Custom ROM or, customize stock rom.

Comment: In many tryouts customizing apps, i found out that there are numbers of errors occur when the system apps are uninstalled. If ever somehow, we can develop a phone that the only system apps present are 'Settings' and 'Sim Tool Kit'. We do know that we can install any kind of apps which we can use in replacing the basic applications installed firstly by the manufacturer.